# Error while loading data in Teradata using proc append (SAS EG 14.1)

Tags: sas, teradata

I am getting below error while appending data in a Teradata table from SAS

**ERROR: Teradata connection: No more room in database TINYDB. Correct error and
restart as an APPEND process with option TPT_RESTART=YES. Since no checkpoints were
taken, if the previous run used FIRSTOBS=n, use the same value in the restart.**

I don't know why i am getting this error for one table, because i am able to append other Teradata tables.

I am using simple proc append

```
proc append data=table1 base=table2 (MULTILOAD=YES TPT=YES) force;
run;
```

Please suggest why its giving above error just for one table, while appending in other Teradata tables is working fine.

Thanks

#

Adding
**Just one explanation, if i remove (MULTILOAD=YES TPT=YES) from the Proc Append Statement, then it will work, but will take huge amount of time**

Comment: How much room is left in this `tinydb`? TPT/MLOAD create tables on the fly and remove them when finished. One of those tables (the worktable) contains a copy of the source data (I believe) before it's loaded to your target table that you've specified in your line of code. It could be that your `tinydb` simply doesn't have the room to allow this type of loading. As you mentioned though, the alternative load type (without TPT/MLOAD) is going to be very slow as it's essentially single line inserts. If it is a size issue, then perhaps hit up your DBA for some extra space.

Comment: You can threaten your DBA that you will use single inserts since that seems to work fine if they can't spare a gb or two more for your database. That should get them to move.

Comment: Check for skew as well, if you're filling up one amp you still get this same message.